# Atributo da Entidade baseado em um campo de uma outra tabela - Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, restful

Tenho um microserviço levantado utilizando o Spring, RestFul e o Hibernate. Gostaria de saber como consigo modificar um atributo deste microserviço json, baseado em uma condição, obtida através de uma consulta ao banco.

Abaixo, um pedaço do código da minha `Entity`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "funcoes")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(allowGetters = true)
public class Funcoes {

@Id
@Column(name = "FUNCOD")
private String funcod;


@Column(name = "FUNFOR")
private String funfor;


@Column(name = "SISTEMA")
private String sistema;

}
}
```

Gostaria de comparar o atributo `sistema`, para se, baseado em uma consulta, exibir um valor `x` ou um valor `y` em meu json.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa de mais flexibilidade para fazer o que quer. E está tendo este problema por estar usando a entidade JPA também para representar o Json. Em geral, é melhor evitar misturar estas duas responsabilidades.

O que indico para você é criar uma nova classe que será usada **apenas** para representar as informações no Json. Podemos chamar ela de `FuncoesJson` ou `FuncoesDto`:

```
public class FuncoesDto {

    private String funcod;
    private String funfor;
    private String sistema;

    //gets e sets

}
```

Para você alterar o que vai na variável `sistema`, você pode tomar esta decisão antes de popular ela com as informações da entidade `Funcoes`. Veja um exemplo:

```
Funcoes funcoes = em.findOne(123L, Funcoes.class);

FuncoesDto dto = new FuncoesDto();
dto.setFuncod(funcoes.getFuncod());
dto.setFunfor(funcoes.getFunfor());

if (funcoes.getSistema().equals("valorConsulta")) {
    dto.setSistema("X");
} else {
    dto.setSistema("Y");
}

return dto;
```